# Is it possible to create a string array secret in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I'm trying to store a string array as a secret; I have this `secrets.yml` file that I'm using in my local environment and works perfectly (values are for explanation purposes only):

**secrets.yml**

```yaml
passwordz:
  - pass_001
  - pass_002
  - pass_003
```

The idea is to be able to store multiple passwords, and I want to use them as part of a k8s secret but had no luck so far; something like this:

**k8s-secrets.yml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: master-passwordz
type: Opaque
data:
  secrets.yml: |-
    passwordz: CiAgLSBwYXNzXzAwMQogIC0gcGFzc18wMDIKICAtIHBhc3NfMDAz
```

At the time to try to apply this secret:

```sh
kubectl apply -f ./k8s-secrets.yml
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "k8s-secrets.yml": Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: v1.Secret.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.TypeMeta: Kind: Data: decode base64: illegal base64 data at input byte 3
```

Any idea if it's possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Could you try using "stringData" instead of "data". AFAIK this key should be used when you don't provide complete base64 encoded data in Secrets.

Answer (score 2):

No, the values must be a `[]byte`, i.e. a string of some kind. You would have to store your array with some kind of encoding (usually JSON) so it's a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: master-passwordz
type: Opaque
data:
    passwordz__0: pass_001
    passwordz__1: pass_002
    passwordz__2: pass_003
```

How about doing it this way?